# Gaze tracking for just eyes ARKit

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, eye-tracking

It seems like gaze tracking only works if the entire face is detected using Apple's ARKit. Is there a way around this, where a close-up of the eyes can still be tracked?

Answer (score 0):

You're right saying that ARKit must detect an entire face in order to work with Gaze Tracking, not a half of face. Face detection is ARKit`s inner feature with a limited functionality borrowed from Vision framework. There's no workaround for Gaze Tracking in ARKit 3.5 in case an entire face isn't yet detected.

Watch Worldwide Developers Conference 2019 `Introducing ARKit 3.0` video (**time 37:30**) to find out how faces are detected in ARKit 3.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Now in 2023, the latest ARKit still only supports eye tracking via the ARFaceAnchor, which means it requires to detect the entire or most parts of the face. A close-up still seems impossible.

You can find the documentation related to eye tracking [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor/2968192-lookatpoint). You will see it requires the whole face detection.